# Jquery removeClass + addClass?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to add an arrow that changes to my accordion menu. I believe I need the removeClass  function of Jquery.

I've got this far at the moment:

HTML/PHP:

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
            <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
            <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                <dt class=""><a href="/"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></a></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not(:first)").hide();
    jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt a").click(function(){
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
        jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown("fast");;

        return false;

        jQuery('.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
        thisObj.addClass('selected');
        var content = thisObj.parent().next();
        content.slideDown('fast');

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#narrow-by-list >  dt a {
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-image: url('/images/bullet.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
#narrow-by-list > dt a.selected{
    background-image: url('/images/bulletselected.png');
}
```

This all works with the accordion menu and add's an image next to the top level titles. However I'm unsure how or why the select is not appearing in the HTML or changing the image for me? Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong. I don't fully understand Jquery as you can probably tell!

Thanks

Comment: For a start, no code will be executed after `return false;`, so remove the first one of them.

Comment: If I remove the first return false; it makes my top level menu's into links?

Comment: Can you post the rendered page, instead of the php?

Comment: sure, this is with the first return false; removed:

http://jsfiddle.net/ADwYa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt").first().addClass('selected'); 
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not(:first)").hide();
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not(:first)").hide();
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt a").click(function(event){
           if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('selected'))
           {
               return false;
           }
           event.preventDefault();
           jQuery('.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
           jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected'); 
           jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
           jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown("fast");                      
           return false;
        });
    });
```

**EDIT**
Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ADwYa/4/)

Comment: This makes all of the menu's expand and all have the none selected image.

Comment: check the fiddle. Please pay attention to changes in css !

Comment: Yo should also add 'selected' class to the first element by default

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to use jQuery not $ due to conflict on magento. How would I go about adding the class selected to just the first link when they are dynamically created? Also with the changes to the css and jquery it makes my main title links into hyper links.

Comment: Hey that's great, its nearly working. However the selected option shows both the selected image and non selected image?

Comment: Fixed by removing the a from the #narrow-by-list >  dt a  in the css.